# I need closing ) parenthesis?

Tags: c#, linq, trim

my code adding semicolon to end of each line... But I need closing ) parenthesis on my second sentence on richtextbox1.  how can I add correctly?

***NOT: my second sentence can end with any word, which means succession s.Endwith("no") replace ("no",");").....not a option to use!.***

***My code only puts ; end of each line***

```
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
List<string> ToAdd = new List<string>();

string filter = ")";

foreach (string s in lines)
{
string hold = s;
if (s.EndsWith(")"))
hold = s.Replace(filter, ";");
}
richTextBox1.Lines = ToAdd.ToArray();
```

***My Result***

```
This is my sentence (Yes);
This is my sentence (Yes) or no; 
This is my sentence (Yes);
This is my sentence (Yes);
```

***I want this result:***

```
This is my sentence (Yes);
This is my sentence (Yes) or no);
This is my sentence (Yes);
This is my sentence (Yes);
```

Comment: `if((line.Trim() + ";").Length <= 2) continue;`

Comment: Where I am going to add this?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
    OracleDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
    {
     reader.Read();

    string[] split = reader[0].ToString().Trim().Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     foreach (string line in split)
    {
     if(line.Trim()==")")
    richTextBox1.AppendText(line.Trim() + ";" + Environment.NewLine);
     else
  richTextBox1.AppendText(line.Trim() + Environment.NewLine);
    }  
    }
```

Edit:

Before for loop, try following:

```
if(reader[0].toString()==")")
reader[0].append(";")
```

(Not exactly the same, but can continue with this logic)

Comment: I got result like this: This is my sentence (Yes)
This is my sentence (Yes) or no         );
This is my sentence (Yes)

Comment: I eadit my question. Thanks

Comment: @user2760129 instead of s.EndsWith(")"), try s.contains(")")

Comment: my sentence becomes like this after your succession: This is my sentence (Yes;
This is my sentence (Yes; or no; 
This is my sentence (Yes;
This is my sentence (Yes;